# Rails Active Storage file static path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is it possible to get the static path of the files stored by Active Storage. As now I am storing the files in Google Cloud Service and I am getting the following output.

```
<%= image_tag f.image, class: "", alt: f.title  %>
```

http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--a00c433792f57ea90a8b6287d6ced45bc7e009ed/gokyo-lake-at-kongmo-la-pass.jpg

Whenever I click on the above URL, the image opens with the Google storage [path](https://storage.googleapis.com/karuna/nnSiY7NeQA2b8URjnfCGvKpf?GoogleAccessId=meetmyhotel-1546940545267%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1562240138&Signature=dAYE2VX2i4rS6l7pd5zQR8Ex0CD3X7GHeoBcagoeqNp63bmJLBOimLUrRQLF9UxjcMb155Z%2BENnFnW9x%2FtdWBr3NNrywNbw2EC3hXHYqJ%2FVTQ0KgZsYPMN2nOZo%2Bhc4iN78phjIj6oNRi26yQOGpYIMaivncj5QAs3VPn5JX%2Bhcv%2FkC4xTZX%2Bn4nRO4s8OHEDW8buFIQfIBaCWk%2BP9%2FM62n%2FY%2B01XwKkGZWRAgUQwD5BuSkD5Av0kg8gkSVr68i1U3MQGYO%2F3xZo4wSZ3ULC%2BXwN4YNTRKxzsc%2BDnSvd5om5oSzq%2F4Fwt3mu9zc3UuOF6ued%2FT5oS8AEPBH3s1ZjJg%3D%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22gokyo-lake-at-kongmo-la-pass.jpg%22%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27gokyo-lake-at-kongmo-la-pass.jpg&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg).

Therefore, is it possible to get the static path? Also how to replace the `../rails/active_storage/blobs with ../uploads`.

Also, when I try to share the post in Facebook, Facebook doesn't pull the image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--a00c433792f57ea90a8b6287d6ced45bc7e009ed/gokyo-lake-at-kongmo-la-pass.jpg" />
```

I am using Rails 5.2.3.

Comment: Just as a heads up, I would suggest not using active storage yet. I tried it a few months back and there's a lot of missing features. Now that paperclip is going to be deprecated, I found a very cool and well documented gem called Shrine. You can find it here: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine

Comment: @Waclock now I cannot go away form using active storage since I have updated my application with active storage.

Comment: I understand, it's a process I had to go through a couple of months ago and it was really a pain that there's lots of features that it's currently missing.

Comment: I think for me its the best to wait for next Rails update with a hope that the missing features will be added in next version.

Comment: What is facebook url debugger saying? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Have you rescraped the URL?